# What are these "balls" that we found in Uruguay?

Tags: identify-this, uruguay

We found a bunch of these balls across "Rio del Plata" in Montevideo or in the coast of Uruguay (Punta del Este).

There is a liquid in the ball. Also, it has a soft skin.

[image]

Comment: Ship load of breast implants? :X

Comment: I do not think so. It is smaller than Breast implants. The size is a little bit more than a chicken egg. However, you describe very well, it looks like a  
Breast implant.

Comment: Could they be from kelp? Typically I would expect kelp balls to look a more [like this](http://jamtsisu.com/albums/san-benitos/great-balls-of-kelp-2/) but these might be some variety I'm not aware of.

Comment: Is the skin made of latex?

Comment: [Eggs of some marine creature](http://courses.washington.edu/chordate/453photos/urogenital_photos/shark-eggs.jpg)?

Comment: What's the paracord bracelet? It's more interesting. ping @Willeke also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It might be a large specimen of *[Valonia ventricosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valonia_ventricosa)*, also called "bubble algae" or "sailor's eyeball".

Comment: I have searched by Valonia ventricosa and it looks like green. Is it right?

Comment: _V. ventricosa_ is photosynthetic (makes its own food from sunlight) and so is typically green when healthy, but can be a golden or brownish color when out of the sun for a few days.

Answer (score 5):

If they haven't exploded yet, in addition to liquid, you will find some embryos [inside](https://wamas.org/forums/topic/54772-giant-gastropod-egg-capsules-on-a-beach-in-argentina/).

They are very popular among Uruguayan coasts, that lead to wrongly associating them with *shark eggs* or *turtle eggs*.

Commonly, they are known as **huevos de caracol negro** (EN: black sea snail), **voluta negra** (because of its family: *Volutidae*) or **ovicápsulas con embriones de caracoles** (ovicápsula: from Latin: *ovum*: egg and  *capsŭla*.

Technically speaking: [Adelomelon](http://www.marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=taxdetails&id=384671)  brasiliana.

[image: sea snail]

> This yellowish capsule, it's filled with food supplements for the embryos, it is located on the seabed and has an oval form, being this a unique feature between sea snails worldwide. After strong winds, many of them remain on the coast, with very low chance of surviving because of the depth where this specie raises. After approximately 2 months, eggs hatch in between 10 and 30 embryos.

- http://www.mgap.gub.uy/sites/default/files/multimedia/1907_caracol_negro_vf_0.pdf
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adelomelon_brasiliana
- http://www.marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=taxdetails&id=384671

Picture from http://www.mgap.gub.uy/sites/default/files/multimedia/1907_caracol_negro_vf_0.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I'm from Uruguay, and we typically call these "turtle eggs" although I'm not sure if the term is accurate.

Comment: Frankly, I doubt those are [turtle eggs](https://www.google.fr/search?q=turtle+egg&tbm=isch). There's no reason for eggs to have transparent skin.

Answer (score 0):

We call them here Agua Viva (Live or living water), AFAIK its irritant, so be careful, I wouldn't touch it.

What I found is that is some kind of relative of jellyfish, look for Medusozoa.